# change wireframe background in blender 2.8

Tags: blender

I am totally new to blender. Check out the following picture:

[image]

My coach changed cylinder to wireframe, so then I change my cylinder to wireframe, however the view is different:

[image]

My question: How do I change to wireframe view? My wireframe background is transparent but first in image is not transparent.

Can any one help? I'm using Blender 2.8

Answer (score 0):

You can change between wireframe/solid/material/and render previews by pressing the z key and confirming your selection in the radial menu.
You may also find the options in the
[overlay dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoBwX.png) useful - located in the top right hand corner of the 3D viewport. Particularly the floor, grid and wireframe options.